# cURL NONCE_NOT_PROVIDED

Tags: linux, api, curl, hash, nonce

I had found these steps for use with a different API. They do not appear to work.

My understanding of nonce is that it is just a random hash you use once. so the creation method should matter little.
I think my issue is with my cURL formatting.

session:

```
# echo -n "/0" > tmp.bin

# echo -n "123nonce=123" | openssl sha256 -binary >> tmp.bin

# cat tmp.bin | openssl sha512 -binary -hmac $(echo -n "mmyykkeeyy" | base64 -d) | base64 -w long_hash

# curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "long_hash" -d "nonce=123" "https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/key/market/GetOrderHistory?market=BTC-TRX&apikey=mmyyykkeeyy"
```

return data:

```
{"success":false,"message":"NONCE_NOT_PROVIDED","result":null}
```

also tried:

```
echo -n "/0/key" > tmp.bin
```

and I also tried creating nonce without the tmp.bin, outputing it to the buffer and using it raw. same nonce error.

adding

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

yields a server 500 error.

known working api v2.0 library, only python and does not suit my needs  [v2.0 python library](https://github.com/mondeja/bittrex_v2/blob/master/bittrex_v2/bittrex.py)

How do I correctly deliver the nonce to the bittrex api using cURL?

UPDATE:

I changed the url in the Bittrex python library to webserver not running https and captured the dead outbound packet in the raw (non encapsulated). Now I can at least see what the know good python library is throwing

[GET packet from known good Python library request in wireshark](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1524244865.png)

```
$ echo -n "/0" > tmp.bin

$ echo -n "123nonce=123" | openssl sha256 -hex
(stdin)= 353f9df92ab1d5e5afe06bb7d1bb42a8ef6654b633d94818007aeafbaf03ca3d

$ echo 353f9df92ab1d5e5afe06bb7d1bb42a8ef6654b633d94818007aeafbaf03ca3d| openssl sha512 -binary -hmac $(echo -n "mmyykkeeyy" | base64 -d) | base64 -w 0

biglonghash


$ curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "biglonghash" "https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/key/market/GetOrderHistory?apikey=mmyykkeeyy&nonce=353f9df92ab1d5e5afe06bb7d1bb42a8ef6654b633d94818007aeafbaf03ca3d&market=BTC-TRX"
```

response:

```
{"success":false,"message":"APISIGN_NOT_PROVIDED","result":null}
```

update2:

```
$ echo -n "/key" > tmp.bin

$ echo -n "123nonce=123" | openssl sha256 -binary >> tmp.bin

$ cat tmp.bin | openssl sha512 -binary -hmac $(echo -n "mmyysseeccrreett" | base64 -d) | base64 -w 0
```

output:

```
biglonghash
```

session:

```
$ curl --get -H "Accept: application/json" -H "apisign:biglonghash" "https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/key/market/GetOrderHistory?apikey=mmyyaappiikkeeyy&nonce=353f9df92ab1d5e5afe06bb7d1bb42a8ef6654b633d94818007aeafbaf03ca3d&market=BTC-TRX"

{"success":false,"message":"INVALID_SIGNATURE","result":null}
```

Comment: Got the same problem with the api. `NONCE_NOT_PROVIDED`. Have u already solved it?